# Power BI - Dynamically change position and size of tiles in a time interval

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, tableau-api, tiles

Please check attached image [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkD7D.jpg)

In Power BI or Tableau want to create a dashboard will have 5 tiles.

4 small tiles in corners and one big tile in center.

Want to Dynamically bring each small tile to the center in a particular time interval say every 2mins.

Data in each of these tiles will be dynamically updated each business day morning.

This will be displayed in a big LED panel.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site expects you to do some work, so please show us what you've started. It's also a good idea to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, this is not possible via Tableau. You would require help of front-end developers for it to dynamically change positions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rearrange the position of the visuals in a report, but you can make a report with 5 pages, where each visual has a page, where it is "on focus" and cycle through these pages.

The cycling can be done in different ways:

1. Use [Presentation mode](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/presentation-mode-in-power-bi-windows-app/) on Windows 10 app.
2. Publish the report to Power BI Service and use [Tab Rotate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-rotate/pjgjpabbgnnoohijnillgbckikfkbjed?hl=en-GB) Chrome plugin (or similar solution, which I'm pretty sure exists for other browsers) and show different pages opened in 5 browser tabs.
3. Publish the report to Power BI Service, [embed](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics) it in your application, and programatically [cycle](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Page-Navigation) through it's pages.
4. Pin tiles for Streaming datasets in 5 dashboards and push data to them (see [Real-time streaming in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming) and [Push data to Power BI streaming datasets without writing any code using Microsoft Flow](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-rows-to-a-power-bi-streaming-dataset-without-writing-any-code-using-microsoft-flow/)).

Automatic data refresh depends on the storage mode of your report - is the data imported or you are using DirectQuery mode. If you publish an imported dataset to Power BI Service, you can [schedule automatic refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-scheduled-refresh). For DirectQuery, either in Power BI Desktop or Power BI Service, you can use [Automatic page refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-automatic-page-refresh).

I will also recommend you to take a look at [Data refresh in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data) article.